# Adding over 30 days to 1900-01-01

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I add over 30 days in C++ to 1900-01-01 date approx. over 1000 days and then format the `time_t` after the addition to get a non-broken date.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
int tmp = 1000;
struct std::tm tm;
std::istringstream ss("1900-01-01");
ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d");
tm.tm_mday = tm.tm_mday + tmp;
return mktime(&tm);
```

Comment: You could use the [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do? Because I read the question several times now, and I still don't understand it.

Comment: okay i have shared my 1st attempt

Comment: Initially you told about time_t, that is a numeric type, and you can add days * 86400. This is C. You are using C++, then use std::chrono::days or std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<604800>> prior C++20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [Joseph Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69047745/7582247)'s very good suggestion to check out *the* date/time library to use, I'll show how you could get further using your current idea.

You also have much support in [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) nowadays so read about that too.

You try to add the days in the wrong domain, to `std::tm`. Instead, convert the `std::tm` to `time_t` and add the days to that - then convert the result back to `std::tm`.

Example:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    int days = 1000;

    std::tm tm{};
    std::istringstream ss("1900-01-01");

    if(ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d")) {
        tm.tm_isdst = -1; // let mktime "guess" if DST is effect

        // convert to time_t and add 1000 days. 1 day = 24*60*60 seconds
        std::time_t result = std::mktime(&tm) + days * 60*60*24;
 
        // back to std::tm
        tm = *std::localtime(&result);

        // print result
        std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d") << '\n';
    }
}
```

Note: This technique will sometimes get the wrong answer. If for the computer's local time zone the UTC offset at 1900-01-01 is greater than it is at 1900-01-01 + days, then the result will be one day less than it should. This happens (for example) with the IANA time zone America/Anchorage with days == 232. It happens again with Africa/Cairo at days == 273.

A better option is clearly to use the facilities in `chrono` or Howard Hinnant's `date` library as [demonstrated by Howard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077483/7582247).

Comment: This technique will sometimes get the wrong answer.  If for the computer's local time zone the UTC offset at 1900-01-01 is greater than it is at 1900-01-01 + days, then the result will be one day less than it should.  This happens (for example) with the IANA time zone America/Anchorage with days == 232.  It happens again with Africa/Cairo at days == 273.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Oups. Is this salvageable (without too much fuzz) or should I recommend OP to unaccept so I can delete the answer?

Comment: I haven't come up with a way to salvage it yet, and admittedly haven't put much time into it.  I've seen this technique before, but today was the first time I tested it, and realized how it could go wrong.  Your answer might be more valuable not-deleted in order to demonstrate the sneaky flaw.  And I also don't know how much can be done anyway with the question closed.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Good point and thanks for checking it out. I'm adding your word of caution to the answer and leave it at that.

Answer (score 3):

Date/time handling in C++ is awkward as awkward can be. Howard Hinnant has a great library you may want to look at:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

The problem is complicated. If you use local dates, you can't add a fixed amount of time due to daylight savings time and leap seconds. You could use GMT, but you're still subject to leap seconds.

But Howard's library make make this much easier for you. I'd take a peek.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest Visual Studio 2019, then you have C++20 `<chrono>` which can solve this problem without the errors associated with the `mktime`/`localtime` technique demonstrated in [Ted Lyngmo's answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69047819/576911).

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    // Hold the amount to add in the type std::chrono::days (a chrono duration)
    std::chrono::days days{1000};
    // std::chrono::sys_days is a Unix Time chrono::time_point with precision days
    std::chrono::sys_days tp;
    std::istringstream ss("1900-01-01");

    if(ss >> std::chrono::parse("%F", tp)) {
        // No need to involve time zones.
        // Just add and print out
        std::cout << tp + days << '\n';  // 1902-09-28
    }
}
```

This program has the same behavior and output as [Ted's answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69047819/576911).  But if there's no need to read the "constant" 1900-01-01 out of a stream, then we can do even better.  C++20 can make 1900-01-01 a compile-time constant:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::chrono::days days{1000};
    constexpr std::chrono::sys_days tp = 1900y/01/01;  // Compile-time date literal
    // Just add and print out
    std::cout << tp + days << '\n';  // 1902-09-28
}
```

These solutions don't involve time zones at all.  It is simply adding a number of days to a date.  The simplicity makes for efficient code and reduces the chance for errors associated with increased complexity.

If you don't have the latest Visual Studio 2019, or otherwise don't have access to C++20, you can use [Howard's free, open-source, header-only "date.h" C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) referred to in [Joseph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69047745/576911) with nearly identical syntax.

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date::literals;
    date::days days{1000};
    constexpr date::sys_days tp = 1900_y/01/01;  // Compile-time date literal
    // Just add and print out
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << tp + days << '\n';  // 1902-09-28
}
```

- The C++20 chrono additions are in `namespace date` instead of `namespace std::chrono`.
- The `year` literal is spelled `_y` instead of `y`.
- The `time_point` streaming operators won't be found by ADL and have to be manually exposed in `namespace date`.